# How many calls to submit to use with newWorkStealingPool?

Tags: java, multithreading

Im reading about **Executors.newWorkStealingPool** and am wondering about getting it setup.

My thread(s) will be pulling from a **LinkedBlockingQueue** so will running continuously (unless blocked at the 'take' call).

Assume that I don't know how many cores will be provided on the host where this code will run. How do I know how many instances of my Runnable object to add?

```
Runnable processRecord = () -> {
    try {
        consumeRecord(blockingQueue.take());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

public void setup() {
    ExecutorService workPool = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
```

-----> how many instances of my thread do I pass in?

```
    workPool.submit(processRecord);
}
```

More likely - how do I (properly) use this thread construct?

Comment: Do you really need a work-stealing pool (i.e. `ForkJoinPool` in the current implementations)?

Comment: `Runnable`s submitted to a work-stealing pool (`ForkJoinPool`) are executed once (like in any other thread pool). With the example implementation for `processRecord` you need to submit one for each element in the `blockingQueue`

Comment: @ThomasKläger Post this as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Runnables` submitted to a work-stealing pool (`ForkJoinPool`) are executed once (like in any other thread pool).

With the example implementation for `processRecord` you need to submit one for each element in the `blockingQueue`